# Filter data already filtered through subscription in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, publish-subscribe

If I have a subscription

```
Meteor.publish('itemsByProjectId', function (projectId) {
  check(projectId, String);
  return Items.find({ projectId: projectId});
});
```

then I only subscribe items related to the project.

Do I also have to use `Items.find({ projectId: projectId })` when outputting the items in the templates or is it sufficient to use `Items.find()` since the collection is already filtered through the subscription.

What is best practice in such situations? I don't see the need for filtering the data again.

Answer (score 1):

it would depend on if you had sent any other docs from the Items collection to the client. If you had used subs manager to cache a past sub to the items collection or were using another subscription to the Items collection, then you would want to be more specific in your client side find within a template helper. However, if you are certain that the only docs of the item collection that will be on the client at this point are the ones with the correct projectId, then it would be ok to just use the find without a selector.

Comment: Also remember - even if that is the only active subscription which touches that collection right now, in the future you might add another subscription. In this case, if you didn't add the extra selector on the client, you're likely to introduce bugs.